# Are there alternate ways to meet Jack in Mass Effect 3?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I waited too long and the Grissom Academy mission went away =(.  Is there any other way I can meet Jack in ME 3?  Or was that the only chance?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

> Well, that's not entirely true. You'll see her again, but it [won't be friendly.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yPJj8efNskM)

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't do the Grissom Academy mission, Jack will appear in a later mission [as a Cerberus Phantom](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Phantom#Jack). Aside from using her trademark taunts, she will be no different from any other Phantom.

This is similar to how Morinth will appear as a Banshee unless you killed her during Samara's loyalty mission in ME2.